# How to deal with statistically insignificant factors?

Tags: statistical-significance, experiment-design, fractional-factorial

I used $2^4$ factorial design to screen significance of the factors $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$. It turned out that $A$ and $B$ were significant, whereas $C$ and $D$ were not.

Since there is no need to consider insignificant factors in further experiments, could I set them to arbitrarily chosen constant values? For example, in the response surface modeling, I would use Central Composite Design for $A$ and $B$, but keep $C$ and $D$ at some convenient values, say $\gamma$ and $\delta$.

Another question is do $\gamma$ and $\delta$ have to be between the low and high values of $C$ and $D$, that were used during the screening phase, or can I choose even values outside that range?

Comment: Why is there no need to consider insignificant factors in further experiments ? What are the effect sizes ? Does your experiment have sufficient power to detect the effect sizes you are interested in ? Relying on statistical significance, based on an arbitrary p value cut-off, is rather dangerous.

Comment: The effect sizes are around `0.03` for the insignificant effects, and `0.7` and `0.85` for those that proved to be significant.